# Request For Java Regex String

Tags: java, regex

i was wondering if anybody could help me with a RegEx i need to use for matching strings in the format `"4%,6%,8%,9%" "(Number)(Percentage)(comma)(number)(percentage)....N"`

I tried hard to get this one `^[\d*(?:%),]+$` but its matching the format `"4%,2,6,5%"` (numbers without percentage simbol).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Should be like :   ^\d+%(?:,\d+%)+$

Comment: `[]` is a character class, use `()` for grouping

Comment: You could use this cool resource: http://www.txt2re.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex like below,

```
^\d+%(?:,\d+%)+$
```

`(?:,\d+%)+` Allows one or more strings of this `,<number>%` format.

**OR**

```
^\d+%(?:,\d+%)*$
```

`(?:,\d+%)*` Allows zero or more strings of this  `,<number>%` format.

Comment: Thats a pretty fast answer, Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).